# Index (SPX) weekly return with a condition

Tags: finance

I am looking at statistics of the weekly returns of SPX. Taking all the weeks starting from 1st Jan 2010, the hisotgram of the returns is:

```
dataweekly = 
  FinancialData["^SPX", "OHLCV", {{2010, 1, 1}, Today, "Week"}][
    "Path"][[All, 2]];
datapercweekly = 
  100*(dataweekly[[All, 4]] - dataweekly[[All, 1]])/
    dataweekly[[All, 1]];
edistT = EstimatedDistribution[datapercweekly, 
   StudentTDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma], \[Nu]]];

Show[Histogram[datapercweekly, {-8, 8, 0.2}, "PDF", Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"weekly returns [%]", "PDF [-]"}, ImageSize -> 600, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 34, FontFamily -> "Arial"},
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[3]]],
 Plot[PDF[edistT, x], {x, -8, 8}, PlotStyle -> Thick]]
```

Now, I would like to do something more complex and visualize the returns of the weeks following a weekly return of x (let us assume 1%). Any idea is welcome.

Comment: Is a “week” here Monday-Friday, or any contiguous five trading days?

Comment: This is interesting. I would like to see both. But my priority is Mon-Fri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the dataset already breaks the data into weeks for you, this is pretty simple. I combine returns from the earlier week with returns from the later week in a two-members list, select the two-member lists that meet the test, then throw out the part about the earlier week. I'm left with a list of changes (*100) for the weeks you care about, and you can do whatever statistical evaluation of that dataset you like.

```
thisWeekChangeWithGoodLastWeek = 
  Select[Transpose[{Drop[datapercweekly, -1](*last week*), 
      Drop[datapercweekly, 1](*this week*)}], #[[1]] > 1. &][[All, 2]];

Histogram[thisWeekChangeWithGoodLastWeek]
```